# JOIN query MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm trying to retrieve multiple records with the following query

```
SELECT  
  p.title, i.filename , p.id , p.category_id,  p.coverfilename 
FROM 
  `games` p 
JOIN (
  select
    i2.id_game,   min(i2.filename) as filename
  from
    images i2 
  group by
    i2.id_game
) i
 on i.id_game=p.id WHERE p.category_id = 3
```

But instead of returning 7 records from DB. Its only retrieving one. Can someone point me to how to re-do this query to retrieve all records that match

```
"category_id = 3"
```

updated format

Comment: show your tables structures with their data

Comment: Sample data and output

Comment: if you have only one i2.idle _game then its possiba

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.title, i.filename, p.id, p.category_id, p.coverfilename
  from games p, images i
 where i.id_game = p.id
   and p.category_id = 3
```

Comment: Hi this is returning the correct number or results, however the title of the games are all the same when there should be different game titles, thanks

Comment: Actually some of the games don't have a "filename" (empty) from the images table. is there any way to revert to the coverfilename if not found?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.title, IF(i.filename='',p.coverfilename,i.filename) as FILE_DATA, p.id, p.category_id, p.coverfilename 
from games p, images i where i.id_game = p.id and p.category_id = 3
```

Comment: I dont just edit the answer. check i put condition if the filename contain no data it will display the coverfilename in place of filename from select query. Just run the query having null value in filename field.